# Selection Expert Query

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I need a bit of help with a report I'm working on, namely, I need a formula or a filter that would show me repeat calls (a repeat call would be when a new call (Call Time) is raised within 7 working days of the call closure (Close Time) for that particular asset(Asset Number).

Below columns are included in my report:

Asset Number - integer

Site Name - string

Call Time - datetime

Close Time - datetime

Full Name - string

Comments - memo

PS: the above comes from a SQL Server 2017.

I hope the above is enough for somebody to help out.

I've already tried to work it out using the Select Expert but I can't seem to work it out.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
    SELECT 
     "T_Telesales_Service"."call_time",
     "T_Employee"."NAME",
     "T_Employee"."SURNAME",
     "T_Employee"."GROUP_ID",
     "T_Telesales_Service"."vm_id",
     "T_POS"."DESCRIPTION_1",
     "T_Telesales_Service"."close_time",
     "T_Telesales_Service"."record_id",
     "T_Telesales_Service"."eng_comments"

     FROM 
    (("Vendmanager"."dbo"."T_Telesales_Service" "T_Telesales_Service" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Vendmanager"."dbo"."T_Employee" "T_Employee" ON "T_Telesales_Service"."assigned_id"="T_Employee"."RECORD_ID") 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Vendmanager"."dbo"."T_POS" "T_POS" ON "T_Telesales_Service"."pos_id"="T_POS"."RECORD_ID") 
INNER JOIN "Vendmanager"."dbo"."T_Library_Sys" "T_Library_Sys" ON "T_Telesales_Service"."status_id"="T_Library_Sys"."record_id"

     WHERE  
     ("T_Employee"."GROUP_ID"=2 OR "T_Employee"."GROUP_ID"=3)

     ORDER BY 
     "T_Telesales_Service"."vm_id", "T_Telesales_Service"."call_time"
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original version of the question.

You can use `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(call_time) over (partition by assetnumber order by call_time) as next_call_time
      from t
     ) t
where next_call_time < dateadd(day, 7, call_time);
```

Comment: Would you be able to help me with the whole query? I've added my current SQL query in the description of the issue.

Comment: @JonaszBadas . . . You can use a CTE to define your current query as a CTE and then follow the example in this answer.